# Adding one to a value in C++ for a PIC Micro

Tags: pic, c++

I have a PIC 12f629 and I am going to program it. I have a value for the output:

```
GPIO = 0b000000;
```

and am using it in a loop that iterates 10 times:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

My problem is that I need to increment `GPIO` to be able to address different memory regions.

How could I do that in C++?

Comment: You can just output the integer directly (binary is just how it's represented in the literal) but if you're looping 10 times what do you want it to do when i is 8 for example which won't fit into a three bit number?

Comment: I want to send signal to output port that is why i use binary format.

Comment: the next value is ob00000100 or 0b00000011? you want to add decimal at i th location or simply 1+1=2?

Comment: GPIO is not binary value, it is (unsigned) char!

Comment: How you express a variable in code (the [numeric base](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/hex/)) has nothing to do with how the number can be used.

Answer (score 6):

Binary is just how the literal `0b000000` is expressed in the program, internally they are all binary numbers so `0x00` for hexadecimal or just a straight `0` for decimal would all do the same thing. Your code should be as simple as this for cycling the first three bits for the port:

```
for(i=0; i < 8; i++)
    GPIO = i;
```

Note though that that will overwrite the contents of the whole port so if you're using other parts of the port for output you may want to keep track of it's state. Either that or you may be able to use code such as the following to just set the lower three bits depending on whether the compiler and PIC being used allows that GPIO value to be read back:

```
for(i=0; i < 8; i++)
    GPIO = (GPIO & 0b11111000) | i;
```

That just uses an AND operator to read back the port value with the lower three bits cleared and then uses an OR operator to include the contents of `i`.